# Problem with Irreductible Polynomials in $k[x]$, $k$ be an field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I don't have idea, how i can prove this:
Let $k$ be a field, and let $f(x) = a_{0} + a_{1}x + \cdots + a_{n}x^{n} \in k[x]$ have degree $n$ and nonzero constant term $a_0$. Prove that if $f(x)$ is irreducible, then so is $a_{n} + a_{n−1}x +\cdots+a_{0}x^{n}$.

Comment: Please avoid [no clue questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). You might not know how to solve this problem, but I don't believe you are clueless.

Comment: Note:  $f(x)=x^n\left(a_n+a_{n-1}\frac1x+\cdots+a_0\left(\frac1x\right)^n\right)$